# how limit to one result per value in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a view and a query resists my efforts.
the goal is to find for each 'pm' which 'nom_releve' is most present and to make it go up.

I have managed so far to sort and find which is the most present.
but I can not bring out ONLY the most present for each pm.
I am still a beginner in SQL, I would like if possible a helping hand to unblock the situation.

Thank you all.

here is my request:

```
SELECT pm, nom_releve 
FROM genie_civil.v_appui 
GROUP BY pm, nom_releve 
ORDER BY pm, COUNT(nom_releve) DESC;
```

here is a capture of the result.

I framed a few identical 'pm', so I would only need the first result for each 'pm'

[image: result query]

Comment: In relational databases rows do not have inherent ordering. How do you want to define "...the first result for each 'pm'"?

Comment: precisely, I don't know, if that finds my request impossible to process.

Comment: `ORDER BY` is irrelevant in views.

Comment: Actually, what's the expected result? If you could include that it would be simple to understand.

Comment: in fact the expected result is to show which 'nom_releve' is most present for each 'pm'.
the answer is actually just below.
but yes indeed, the ORDER BY is not relevant, it is just there to process and control the result visually for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pm) pm, nom_releve 
FROM genie_civil.v_appui 
GROUP BY pm, nom_releve 
ORDER BY pm, COUNT(nom_releve) DESC;
```

Comment: thanks, it's just perfect, 
I didn't know DISTINCT ON, but now yes.

Comment: `DISTINCT ON` is a very useful extension in PostgreSQL. Not standard, but very good.